# Свойства массива и объекта в одном флаконе?

Tags: javascript

Нужна структура для организации данных в JS, которая будет удовлетворять следующим условиям:
Возможность задавать строку в качестве ключа (как умеет объект).
Упорядоченность. Возможность сортировать, получить индекс по значению, следующий элемент, предыдущий и т.д. (как умеет массив)

Есть ли какое-то решение с нормальной поддержкой браузерами?

Comment: Массив объектов может быть

Comment: нет, встроенные объекты не удовлетворяют этим требованиям, но ты всегда можно написать свой класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `javascript` нет такой конструкции, но есть возможность добиться желаемого эффекта множеством способов. Первое на что стоит обратить внимание, Вам не нужна новая структура данных. Вам подойдет любая имеющуюся + пользовательский итератор. Пользовательский нужен для того, что у Вас была возможность шага в два направления. Нативные итераторы имеют только шаг вперед. Минимальный пример выглядит примерно так -

```js
class HashIterator {
  get length(){
    return this.keys.length;
  }
  
  constructor( hash ){
    this.hash = hash;
    this.keys = Object.keys( this.hash );
    
    this.currentIndex = 0;
  }
  
  hasNext(){
    let isNextValid = this.currentIndex < this.length;
    
    if( ! isNextValid ){
      this.currentIndex = this.length - 1;
    }
    
    return isNextValid;
  }
  hasPrev(){
    let isHasPrevValid = this.currentIndex > -1;
    
    if( ! isHasPrevValid ){
      this.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    
    return isHasPrevValid;
  }
  
  next(){
    return this.hash[ this.keys[ this.currentIndex++ ] ];
  }
  prev(){
    return this.hash[ this.keys[ this.currentIndex-- ] ];
  }
}

let price = {};
price.banana = 70;
price.apple = 100;

let iterator = new HashIterator( price );

while( iterator.hasNext() ){
  console.log( iterator.next() );
}

while( iterator.hasPrev() ){
  console.log( iterator.prev() );
}
```

Можно создать собственный тип `Hash` -

```js
class HashIterator {
  get length(){
    return this.keys.length;
  }
  
  constructor( hash ){
    this.hash = hash;
    this.keys = Object.keys( this.hash );
    
    this.currentIndex = 0;
  }
  
  hasNext(){
    let isNextValid = this.currentIndex < this.length;
    
    if( ! isNextValid ){
      this.currentIndex = this.length - 1;
    }
    
    return isNextValid;
  }
  hasPrev(){
    let isHasPrevValid = this.currentIndex > -1;
    
    if( ! isHasPrevValid ){
      this.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    
    return isHasPrevValid;
  }
  
  next(){
    return this.hash[ this.keys[ this.currentIndex++ ] ];
  }
  prev(){
    return this.hash[ this.keys[ this.currentIndex-- ] ];
  }
}

class Hash {
  constructor(  ){
    this.hash = {};
  }
  
  set( key, value ){
    this.hash[ key ] = value;
  }
  get( key ){
    return this.hash[ key ];
  }
  
  iterator(){
    return new HashIterator( this.hash );
  }
}

let price = new Hash();
price.set( "banana", {price: 70, color: "yellow"} )
price.set( "apple", {price: 100, color: "red"} )

let iterator = price.iterator();

while( iterator.hasNext() ){
  console.log( iterator.next() );
}

while( iterator.hasPrev() ){
  console.log( iterator.prev() );
}
```

Но с другой стороны, мне не очень просто придумать тривиальную задачу для `js` где реально необходим такой функционал, поэтому я просто напомню, что все этого в можно сделать и по другому -

```
let array = [];
array.push({ type: "banana", price: 70 });
array.push({ type: "apple", price: 100 });

let banana = array.find( item => item.type === "banana" );
console.log( banana );

console.log( array.sort( ( a, b ) => a.price < b.price ) );
```

И НУ ОЧЕНЬ близкий по духу нативный вариант -

```
let map = new Map();

map.set( 'banana', { price: 70, color: "yellow" } );
map.set( 'apple', { price: 100, color: "red" } );

console.log( map.get( "banana" ) ); // доступ по ключу

let array = Array.from( map ); // двухмерный массив

let banana = array.find( item => item[ 0 ] === "banana" );

console.log( array.sort( a, b ) => a[ 1 ].price < b[ 1 ].price );
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Я, в общем-то, так и поступил. Создал класс, очень похожий на Ваш Hash + немного кастомного функционала под конкретные нужды. В моем случае отлично подошла кастомная реализация, но теперь я понял, что похожего результат можно было добиться и с помощью массива объектов. Пусть и немного менее красиво. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам подойдёт структура - **LINKED LISTS**

Связные списки являются общей структурой данных, которая часто используется для хранения других структур данных из-за своей способности эффективно добавлять элементы к началу, середине и в конце.

```
 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Выглядит так:

```
 {
   value: 1,
   next: {
     value: 2,
     next: {
       value: 3,
       next: {...}
     }
   }
 }
```

```js
class LinkedList {

  /*
    В отличие от графа, связанный список имеет один узел. Это известно как "голова"   связанного списка.
    Мы также собираемся отслеживать длину.
  */

  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  /**
   * Во-первых нам нужен способ, чтобы получить значение в заданном положении..
   * Это работает по-другому, чем обычные списки, мы не можем просто перейти к
   * необходимому положению. Вместо этого мы должны двигаться через отдельные узлы.
   */

  get(position) {
    // Начинаем с головы списка
    var current = this.head;

    // Проходим через все элементы, используя node.next, пока мы не достигнем
    // нужной позиции.
    for (var index = 0; index < position; index++) {
      current = current.next;
    }

    // Возвращаем узлы, которые нашли
    return current;
  }

  /**
   * Далее нам нужен способ для добавления узлов в заданное положение.
   *
   * Метод добавления, который принимает значение и позицию.
   */

  add(value, position) {
    // Сначала нужно создать узел для хранения нашего значения.
    var node = {
      value: value,
      next: null
    };

    // Нам нужно иметь специальный случай для узлов которые вставляем в начало.
    // Мы установим поле "следующий" для текущей начальной позиции, а затем заменяем его на наш новый узел.
    if (position === 0) {
      node.next = this.head;
      this.head = node;

      // Если мы добавим узел в любом другом положении, мы должны соединить его
      // между текущим узлом и предыдущим узлом.
    } else {
      // Во-первых, найти предыдущий узел и текущий узел.
      var prev = this.get(position - 1);
      var current = prev.next;
      // Затем вставьте новый узел между ними, установив поле "next" 
      // для текущего узла и обновив поле "next" предыдущего узла новым значением.
      node.next = current;
      prev.next = node;
    }

    // Наконец просто увеличиваем длину.
    this.length++;
  }

  /**
   * Последний метод который нам нужен - удалить. Мы просто будем смотреть вверх
   * узла, на его положение и сращивать(splice) его с цепочкой
   */

  remove(position) {
    // Если мы удалим первый узел нам просто нужно установить начало на
    // следующий узел в цепи
    if (position === 0) {
      this.head = this.head.next;

    // Для любой другой позиции, мы должны смотреть вверх предыдущий узла 
    // и установить егок узлу после текущей позиции.
    } else {
      var prev = this.get(position - 1);
      prev.next = prev.next.next;
    }

    // Заием мы просто уменьшаем длину.
    this.length--;
  }
}
```

[Здесь](https://github.com/tsvetkovpro/sources/blob/master/server/itsy-bitsy-data-structures-master/itsy-bitsy-data-structures.js) доступны ещё структуры, реализованные на js:

- List
- HashTable
- Stack
- Queue
- Graph
- LinkedList
- Tree
- BinarySearchTree

Comment: спасибо! Немножко не то, хотелось бы иметь возможность задавать символьные ключи и перемещаться по списку в двух направлениях: current.next(), current.prev(). Но с этим я уже разберусь. Т.е. я правильно понял, что в рамках стандарта ECMAScript 5 эта задача не решается никаким более простым способом, кроме как написать свою реализацию?

Comment: нет. стандартных средств нет. пусть более опытные товарищи поправят если не прав.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо за помощь!